# Arrange two images one below the one another diagonally in a responsive way

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I want to two images diagonally one below another like this, and they should remain like that responsively.

[image]

So far I've got this, but the images are moving when I re-size the window and it is not responsive. Is it possible to make it responsive using bootstrap?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <img class="img-responsive" align="left" src="img1.png" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <img class="img-responsive" align="left" src="img2.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/mozubogici/edit?html,output)

Comment: Do you mean that the images should stay like this in all resolutions?

Comment: @JordiFlores - yeah, that is what I am looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `col-*-offset-*` instead of aligning left/right. Check below snippet for reference.

```css
.p0 {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 p0">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/600x400/green" />
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-6 p0">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/600x400" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```